# beamer theorem box overflow

Tags: tables, beamer

[image]

The theorem box in beamer (using the Warsaw theme) overflows on the right. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}


\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{Test}
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{6cm}}
 \vspace{0cm}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{triangle.jpg}&
 \begin{theorem}
 $a^2+b^2=c^2$
 \end{theorem}
\end{tabular}
}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beamer` has its own means for this situation: `columns`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{4cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{6cm}
 \begin{theorem}
 $a^2+b^2=c^2$
 \end{theorem}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{4cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[thick] (3.9,0) -- (0,0) node[midway,below]{$a$} -- (0,2) node[midway,left]{$b$}
 -- cycle node[midway,above]{$c$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{6cm}
 \begin{theorem}
 $a^2+b^2=c^2$
 \end{theorem}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly.